# How to flush Gstreamer pipeline queue and elements?

Tags: gstreamer

I want to unkink this two queue from pipeline and exchange some element of this queue.

Like that :

```
gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PAUSED); 

gst_element_set_state (sink, GST_STATE_NULL);

gst_element_unlink_many(screen_queue2, **filter2**, **videobox2**, videoBox2_queue, (char* )0);

gst_element_unlink_many(screen_queue4, **filter4**, **videobox4**, videoBox4_queue, (char* )0);

gst_element_link_many(screen_queue2, **filter2**, **videobox4**, videoBox4_queue, (char* )0);

gst_element_link_many(screen_queue4, **filter4**, **videobox2**, videoBox2_queue, (char* )0);
```

but my code crashes, kindly help me out to resolved this crash issue. It works properly when pipeline is in NULL state, but I want to handle this when pipeline is in only PAUSED state.

Comment: Few thoughts: Maybe you have to do the same thing as you would when changing pipe at playing/paused (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/section-dynamic-pipelines.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot John. As I'm new to Gstramer do you have any c code to block element's source pad with a blocking pad probe ? and How to send EOS to element's sink pad ?

Comment: a nice C example is at the end of the page I posted :)

Comment: Hi,I'm trying this way         g_object_set(source3,
            "format", GST_FORMAT_TIME,
            "do-timestamp", TRUE,
            "is-live", TRUE,
            "block", TRUE,
            NULL);

        g_object_set(source4,
            "format", GST_FORMAT_TIME,
            "do-timestamp", TRUE,
            "is-live", TRUE,
            "block", TRUE,
            NULL);

Comment: But source is not blocking due to this Live streaming is not comming.